# how to transpose row to column using Spark-SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following data in my table t1

```
col1    | col2   |
sess-1  | read   |
sess-1  | meet   |
sess-1  | walk   |
sess-2  | watch  |
sess-2  | sleep  |
sess-2  | run    |
sess-2  | drive  |
```

expected output:

```
col1   | col2                  |
sess-1 | read,meet,walk        |
sess-2 | watch,sleep,run,drive |
```

I am using Spark 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Check spark

> aggregateByKey

```
   scala> val babyNamesCSV = sc.parallelize(List(("David", 6), ("Abby", 4), ("David", 5), ("Abby", 5)))
babyNamesCSV: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:12


scala> babyNamesCSV.aggregateByKey(0)((k,v) => v.toInt+k, (v,k) => k+v).collect
res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Abby,9), (David,11))
```

Above example can help to understand

or Aggregation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/api/core/spark/Aggregator.html

Comment: thanks for the reply... what I was asking is little different and I found that by doing some RnD, which I am posting below

Answer (score 0):

```
// create RDD data
scala> val data = sc.parallelize(List(("sess-1","read"), ("sess-1","meet"), 
    ("sess-1","walk"), ("sess-2","watch"),("sess-2","sleep"), 
    ("sess-2","run"),("sess-2","drive")))

//groupByKey will return Iterable[String] CompactBuffer**
scala> val dataCB = data.groupByKey()`

//map CompactBuffer to List
scala> val tx = dataCB.map{case (col1,col2)  => (col1,col2.toList)}.collect

data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] =
ParallelCollectionRDD[211] at parallelize at <console>:26

dataCB: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] =
ShuffledRDD[212] at groupByKey at <console>:30

tx: Array[(String, List[String])] = Array((sess-1,List(read, meet,
walk)), (sess-2,List(watch, sleep, run, drive)))

//groupByKey and map to List can also achieved in one statment
scala> val dataCB = data.groupByKey().map{case (col1,col2)  
    => (col1,col2.toList)}.collect
```